# How to remove row and submit form using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Im trying to do a function that removes a row, and after removing the row I want to submit a form.
Below is code:

```
<button type="button" class="icon fa fa-trash-o a-tabel" value="Submit" style="display:none;"></button>

jQuery(".a-tabel").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#a').find('tr:last').remove();
    jQuery('#zone-form').submit();   
});
```

I can remove the form row and It is submitting the form, but when I refresh the page the deleted row is back :(.
Can someone tell me what is wrong in my code, thanks :).

Comment: because the page refresh it will be back to original undeleted. unless you delete from page that is rendering the html view

Comment: when you refresh page the page knows nothing about what happened the last time it was loaded.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but how can I solve the issue that my code have, thanks.

Comment: Are you using server side dynamic language to output the html? If so remove the row there. Otherwise will need to store the page state, in cookie or localStorage and read that when page loads to decide if row needs removing or not

Comment: @charlietfl Hi! No Im not using server side dynamic language.

Comment: @Tony you have to change your server-side code or data to tell it not to output that row. You haven't shared with us any of that code or structure, so it's difficult to help more at the moment, apart from giving you that simple explanation.

Comment: @Tony if you're not using any server-side code, then where are you submitting the form to??

Comment: @ADyson Im using Django :).

Comment: but django is a framework in a dynamic programming language....you just said you weren't

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, I wrote wrong first.

Comment: @Tony ok well you have to change that server code not to output the table row that you deleted. For that to work in all circumstances, you may need to tell the server which row it was you deleted (perhaps by setting a hidden field with the ID of the deleted row, or something. Depends how your data is structured)

Answer (score 1):

As explained by **Adyson** and **charlietfl** the must is use a server side who check if the form is already submited.

With **Jquery**, you can too use cookie with [js-cookie.js](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

Add data when your form is submited, check if data exist on refresh and delete row. I have make a litle example **CodePen**.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdWXpJ

```
var d = Cookies.get('deleted-row'); // Check if cookie i define

if(d != undefined){ // If cookie is define
  removerow($('#a')); // Send element to function for delete row
}

$(".a-tabel").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  removerow($('#a')); // Send element to function for delete row
  Cookies.set('deleted-row', 'yes'); // add cookie 
  $('#zone-form').submit();   
});

function removerow(el){
  el.find('tr:last').remove(); // Remove your row
}
```

You can delete cookie with the `remove` function `Cookies.remove('deleted-row');`

Comment: Hi! Nice code, but the code is deleting the hole table and not the last row.

Comment: You can just apply this code for your utility. In my example is the last row who deleted. But is the way for make what you want without server side control

Comment: is this solution resolve your issue, please accept this answer. thanks